# Buy/Sell Smart Contract - how to start?

Tags: contract-development

I have a dapp that allows you to upload pictures into blockchain using IPFS and I would like to implement a buy/sell smart contract that will allow users to buy the pictures or to setup terms to sell them.

What is the easiest way to start implementing this? I have looked over tutorials and examples, but I didn't find a good example of a buy smart contract, for example. Do you have any suggestions on what is the best approach or source to start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would embed a watermark in every image uploaded to IPFS and then unembed just because information is accessible to everyone via IPFS and it would make sense to show a preview of what people are purchasing.

As for buying and selling, I recommend examining the ERC standards, see

[real-estate standards](https://github.com/ConsenSys/real-estate-standards) and [erc-1175](https://eips.ethereum.org/eip-1175) if you are looking for tokenized transactions.

Buying and Selling is a fairly basic concept. If a user sends an transaction with ether greater than a specific `buy price` the transaction goes through, and `ownership` of the asset is transferred. A decent contract for buying and selling is available from open-zeppelin [Payment Contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/payment/PaymentSplitter.sol), almost forgot about open zeppelin :P.